# Finite State Machine to model a number counter

Tags: arduino

I have to create a Finite State Machine (FSM) using `enum` and `switch/case` properties coding in Arduino C to create a number counter. I'm supposed to have 16 states: 0-7 counting up and 7-0 counting down. Whenever the user clicks a key on the keyboard, the counting is reversed. For example, it should print `(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0,1,2,3,4,...)`, and then after a key is pressed, `(4,3,2,1,0,7,6,5...)` etc. is printed. I am completely stuck and would like some assistance. Thanks!

I have a general skeleton of the code:

```
enum State {
    0;
    1;
    2;
    // 16 of these...
}

void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
   Serial.println("FSM Forwards & Backwards");
}

void loop() {
    state = nextState(state);
    switch (state) {
       case 0:
       // more states(cases) here
       // create a FSM to determine the next state of the machine.
}

State nextState(State state){
    char input = Serial.read();
    // more states(cases) here
}

bool checkReverse(){
    // which reverses the direction of the counter if a key on the 
    keyboard has been pressed
}
```

Comment: `state = nextState(state);` Where is the function prototype for the foward declaration? What is `state`? Where is the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem? This site is about specific C coding problems, not "how do I . . ?"

Comment: state is of type enum

Comment: `enum State` C is case sensitive.

Comment: Anyway Arduino is not C, but resembles it.

Comment: States are the states to a FSM

Answer (score 0):

Seems like homework to me.
Arduino uses the Wiring language, which is actually C++. It contains a lot of various libraries thought.

You probably want to something like this, take note that its internal state is composed of variables state and direction. It will update the state of the automaton every second. Meanwhile it will scan the incoming data for 'r' character and reverse the direction.

```
struct FSM {
  enum state_t {
    step0,
    step1,
    ...
    step8,
    step9,
    ...
  };
  state_t state;
  bool direction;

  FSM() {state = step0;}
  void nextState(bool toggle) {
    state_t oldState = state;
    state_t ret;
    if(direction) {
      switch(oldState) {
        case step0:
          ret = step8;
          break;
        case step1:
          ret = step8;
          break;
        ...
      }
    else {
      case step0:
        ret = step1;
        break;
      case step1:
        ret = step2;
        break;
      ...
    }
    state = ret; // Update state
    direction = toggle ? !direction: direction; // Update toggle
  }
  int getOutput() {
    switch(state) {
      case step0:
        return 0;
      ...
      case 8:
        return 7;
      case 9:
        return 6;
      ...
};
FSM fsm;
bool toggle = false;
unsigned intlastTime;
void setup() {
        lastTime = millis();
}
void loop() {
        int c = Serial.read();
        if(c == 'r') toggle = ! toggle;

        bool timeToCount = false;
        if(lastTime + 1000 < millis()) { // Every second
                timeToCount = true;
                lastTime = millis();
                fsm.nextState(toggle); // 
                Serial.println(fsm.getOutput());
                toggle = false;
        }


}
```